# How to access url parameters in a stateful component

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

I'm having issues accessing url parameters in a stateful component that has been rendered using react-router's render method. I have read that if I want to pass props into a component with react-router, the best method is to use the render function.

Here is my `App` component with a `Link` and a `Route`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import StatefulComponent from './StatefulComponent.jsx';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: null
    };
  }

  render () {
      return (
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div className="react-root">
            <Link to="/someUrl">I'm a link</Link>
            <Route
              path='/:url'
              render={() => <StatefulComponent value={this.state.value}/>}
            />
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      );
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

When a user clicks on the `Link`, `someUrl` should be accessible in the `StatefulComponent` via props. But I cannot access the url parameters in my stateful component:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class StatefulComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    console.log('URL PARAMS:', props.match.params);

    this.state = {}
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.props.value }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

There is no `match` property on props in the `StatefulComponent`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. When using the render method from react-router, you need to pass `{ match }` into the anonymous function that is passed into the render method and then pass it into the component like a normal prop. See below:

```
<Route
  path='/:url'
  render={({ match }) => <StatefulComponent match={match} value={this.state.value}/>}
/>
```